# Google Form Event / Spreadsheet Cell Move Query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm no programmer or anything of the sort. I have a Google form whose output I need to manipulate in a particular way.

The obvious stuff: When a response comes in I provide my folks at work a cell on the sheet that contains a copy of the form's output, outside of the form data area, to indicate that a particular individual has taken ownership of the response and indicate next steps--call this "spreadsheet only data". No problem adding a cell or two of course. However, as responses come in, the list will get long. So I'd like to sort based off of the response timestamp to bring current responses to the top. Again, no problem...for the form data. However if I sort all new responses to the top my spreadsheet, the "spreadsheet only data" will of course not move with the associated form data. Google forms are easy until you need to track additional data after form submission.

I have tried to abandon sorting and use a script I found to send users to the last edited field, thus providing the ease of sort without the sort problems, but that is just confusing for multiple users. Google does not provide a way to insert cells per se, but it does seem to let me get ranges and move them...as best as I can tell from pawing at the intricacies of scripting found in these forums and the older. This is beyond me if possible, but would it be possible to write a script that on form submit triggers to select a range of columns and move all of those selected cells down 1 row? I don't want to specify selected rows to be moved, just columns, given it is indeterminate how many may be present at any time.

To be clearer, I hope, the issue is that, when sorted, the "spreadsheet only" data will not move down with each new form submission, I hope to find a way to rectify that so that my folks aren't scrolling forever to get to their new response, as they would if I just kept the form data unsorted, and since multiple users make the any "go to last edited cell" solution problematic (the only other solution I can think of to make the unsorted list user friendly enough to where folks wont hate the process).

Thanks for anything anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a filter by selecting just the header rows from the form submission table (gray box) and selecting "Filter" from the "Data" menu. This filter is also added to the "Spreadsheet Only" column as well.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm trying to see how this might help. Although it's not prima facie obvious, I'll mess with filters and see. However, raw form output cannot seem to be filtered this way without an error ("This operation is not permitted because it would alter the structure of this table"), and any copied data from cannot be filtered this way without breaking the function (i.e., SORT or importRANGE fail after filter). So I assume the idea is to sort the spreadsheet only data...hmmm. Still working though the options filter might provide. I really appreciate it. Thanks!